# Titanium ERROR after BSOD

Tags: json, titanium

I've recently encountered an error message with Titanium and I have absoulutely no idea how to resolve it!
It happened when one day my laptop ran out of battery with Titanium running.
Upon restoring power to it after plugging in the power cable, I encountered a BSOD, which led me to restart my computer.

When it restarted, I opened Titanium again, and when I tried to run the emulator or run the app from my Android device, I was hit with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Terry\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 2412, in <module>
[ERROR]     builder.build_and_run(True, avd_id, device_args=device_args, debugger_host=debugger_host)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Terry\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.2.GA\android\builder.py", line 2076, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     last_build_info = simplejson.loads(open(build_info_path, 'r').read())
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Terry\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.2.GA\common\simplejson\__init__.py", line 307, in loads
[ERROR]     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Terry\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.2.GA\common\simplejson\decoder.py", line 335, in decode
[ERROR]     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\Terry\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.0.2.GA\common\simplejson\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
[ERROR]     raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
[ERROR] ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Can anyone help out with this issue please??? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you cleaned the project, thrown away your build?

Comment: erm sorry but how should I go about doing it? I'm pretty new to titanium! :p

Comment: go to your project folder on your harddisk. Remove the `build` folder. That should do it